# Redactor: Assign data attribute

Tags: redactor

According to [redactor’s documentation](https://imperavi.com/redactor/docs/settings/formatting/#s-formattingadd) it should be possible to add a data attribute to a block format. The code below works except from the data-cursor part (the block is styled italic and receives the project__link class).

I checked: The data attribute is already missing in the backend after assigning the block format.

Does someone have experience in adding data attributes to redactor text? Thanks for your help!

```
{
    "link": {
      "title": "Link",
      "api": "module.block.format",
      "args": {
        "tag": "p",
        "attr": {
          "class": "project__link",
          "data-cursor": "project-link"
        },
        "style": {
          "font-style": "italic"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If it helps, here is my complete full.json file found in config/redactor/ folder.

```
{
    "buttons": ["html","undo","format","bold","lists","link"],
    "plugins": ["fullscreen","table"],
    "toolbarFixed": true,
    "buttonsTextLabeled": true,
    "minHeight":"100px",
    "formatting": ["p"],
    "formattingAdd": {
        "heading": {
            "title": "Heading",
            "api": "module.block.format",
            "args": {
                "tag": "h2"
            }
        },
        "sub-heading": {
            "title": "Sub-Heading",
            "api": "module.block.format",
            "args": {
                "tag": "h3"
            }
        },
        "blockquote": {
            "title": "Quote",
            "api": "module.block.format",
            "args": {
                "tag": "blockquote"
            }
        }
    }   
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Paul
You config file does not set a data attribute, does it? I had the hunch that the args part might work but writing
```"args": { "data-cursor": "projekt-link" } ```
still does not add a data attribute. Did I miss something in your code?

Comment: Sorry Moritz, I missunderstood the significance of the data-attribute part of your question. I thought the problem might have been the whole structure of your json file as you only shared part of it.

Comment: Thanks for sharing anyway! No, everything works just fine, only the data attribute is ignored. Cheers to you.